# Target another styled component when input:invalid

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a case like this

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1pa3.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuDlS.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfdrT.png)

how to handle when **input:invalid** then **ErrorMessage** will change **display: block**

I tried like this but it doesn't work
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OybUI.png)

Comment: Can you create a new class and put `display: block;` in there, then add that new class when input is invalid?

Comment: In this case, I just want to use css selector to solve it, is there any way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use conditional rendering with the useState hook: set a boolean to true when the input is invalid and only display the error message if the boolean is true.

If you prefer using CSS and styled components, you need to declare your **ErrorMessage** component before your **Input** component so the Input can target the ErrorMessage. Try this:

```css
export const ErrorMessage = styled.p`
    color: red;
    ...
    display: none;
`
export const Input = styled.input`
    ...
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    &:invalid ~ ${ErrorMessage} {
        display: block;
    }
`
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but my problem is that input component is wrapped by FormInput and ErrorMessage is same level as FormInput so cannot selectors to change display of ErrorMessage when input:invalid. do you have any other way